# Making a Bar Graph from Unsual Data Layout in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying make a bar graph of the data shown below. The x-axis should be "Years" and the y-axis, should be "INCOME," "SPENDING," and "TIPS." In my attempt below, it can be seen that "TIPS" are not following the correct "Year" input.

I created this graph be using the Graph Wizard in Excel.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a pivot chart to make this easier.

Select your data and click Insert>PivotChart.

You can choose whether to put the chart on the same sheet or create a new sheet.

[image]

With the PivotChart object selected, drag Type into "Legend (Series)", Year into "Axis (Categories)" and Dollars into "Values". At first, you'll get a chart that looks like this:

[image]

Right click the chart and choose "Change chart type". In the dialog, select Stacked Column:

[image]

That should give you what you want. If you prefer not to see the silver buttons on the chart, you can right click one of them and choose "Hide all field buttons on chart". You can now format the chart as you'd like. I find it most helpful to select the chart, go to the Design tab on the ribbon and use the "Add chart element" drop-down to select the things I want to add or remove. The details and properties of each can be changed by selecting the element (like the axis, for example) and selecting the "Format" tab on the ribbon.